# Illegal string offset 'distance'

Tags: php, json

```
        <!-- I want to see the content from units tag at json file, and its don't work.  -->
```

1.

```
            $json = file_get_contents('https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22' . "$oras" . '%2C%20' . "$tara" . '%22%20)%20and%20u%3D' . "%27$afisaj%27" . '&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys');

            $obj = json_decode($json);

                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($obj);
                echo "</pre>";

                echo "<br><hr><br>";

                foreach ($obj->query->results->channel->units as $key => $value) {
                    var_dump($key);
                    echo $key['distance']; // there is the problem
                    echo $key . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" . "<br><br>";
                    echo $value . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                }

                echo "<br><hr><br>";

                foreach ($obj->query->results->channel->item->forecast as $key) {
                    echo '<b style="color:red;">Low:</b>' . $key->low .
                    '<b style="color:blue;">High:</b>' . $key->high .
                    '<b style="color:green;">Date</b>' . $key->date .
                    '<b style="color:purple;">Day</b>' . $key->day .
                    '<b style="color:yellow;">Text</b>' . $key->text .
                    "<br>";
                }
?>

       The content at $obj, i want to obtain data from units:
```

2. stdClass Object
           (
               [query] => stdClass Object
                   (
                       [count] => 1
                       [created] => 2016-05-05T19:15:02Z
                       [lang] => en-US
                       [results] => stdClass Object
                           (
                               [channel] => stdClass Object
                                   (
                                       [units] => stdClass Object
                                           (
                                               [distance] => mi
                                               [pressure] => in
                                               [speed] => mph
                                               [temperature] => F
                                           )

   ```
                                   [title] => Yahoo! Weather - Nome, AK, US
                                   [link] => http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Country__Country/*https://weather.yahoo.com/country/state/city-2460286/
                                   [description] => Yahoo! Weather for Nome, AK, US
                                   [language] => en-us
                                   [lastBuildDate] => Thu, 05 May 2016 11:15 AM AKDT
                                   [ttl] => 60
                                   [location] => stdClass Object
                                       (
                                           [city] => Nome
                                           [country] => United States
                                           [region] =>  AK
                                       )

                                   [wind] => stdClass Object
                                       (
                                           [chill] => 30
                                           [direction] => 68
                                           [speed] => 7
                                       )

                                   [atmosphere] => stdClass Object
                                       (
                                           [humidity] => 95
                                           [pressure] => 1006.0
                                           [rising] => 0
                                           [visibility] => 10.6
                                       )

                                   [astronomy] => stdClass Object
                                       (
                                           [sunrise] => 6:13 am
                                           [sunset] => 11:45 pm
                                       )

                                   [image] => stdClass Object
                                       (
                                           [title] => Yahoo! Weather
                                           [width] => 142
                                           [height] => 18
                                           [link] => http://weather.yahoo.com
                                           [url] => http://l.yimg.com/a/i/brand/purplelogo//uh/us/news-wea.gif
                                       )

                                   [item] => stdClass Object
                                       (
                                           [title] => Conditions for Nome, AK, US at 10:00 AM AKDT
                                           [lat] => 64.499474
                                           [long] => -165.405792
                                           [link] => http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Country__Country/*https://weather.yahoo.com/country/state/city-2460286/
                                           [pubDate] => Thu, 05 May 2016 10:00 AM AKDT
                                           [condition] => stdClass Object
                                               (
                                                   [code] => 26
                                                   [date] => Thu, 05 May 2016 10:00 AM AKDT
                                                   [temp] => 34
                                                   [text] => Cloudy
                                               )

                                           [forecast] => Array
                                               (
                                                   [0] => stdClass Object
                                                       (
                                                           [code] => 28
                                                           [date] => 05 May 2016
                                                           [day] => Thu
                                                           [high] => 43
                                                           [low] => 31
                                                           [text] => Mostly Cloudy
                                                       )

                                                   [1] => stdClass Object
                                                       (
                                                           [code] => 34
                                                           [date] => 06 May 2016
                                                           [day] => Fri
                                                           [high] => 43
                                                           [low] => 33
                                                           [text] => Mostly Sunny
                                                       )

                                                   [2] => stdClass Object
                                                       (
                                                           [code] => 28
                                                           [date] => 07 May 2016
                                                           [day] => Sat
                                                           [high] => 39
                                                           [low] => 33
                                                           [text] => Mostly Cloudy
                                                       )

                                                   [3] => stdClass Object
                                                       (
                                                           [code] => 26
                                                           [date] => 08 May 2016
                                                           [day] => Sun
                                                           [high] => 38
                                                           [low] => 31
                                                           [text] => Cloudy
                                                       )

                                                   [4] => stdClass Object
                                                       (
                                                           [code] => 39
                                                           [date] => 09 May 2016
                                                           [day] => Mon
                                                           [high] => 38
                                                           [low] => 37
                                                           [text] => Scattered Showers
                                                       )

                                                   [5] => stdClass Object
                                                       (
                                                           [code] => 12
                                                           [date] => 10 May 2016
                                                           [day] => Tue
                                                           [high] => 38
                                                           [low] => 36
                                                           [text] => Rain
                                                       )

                                                   [6] => stdClass Object
                                                       (
                                                           [code] => 26
                                                           [date] => 11 May 2016
                                                           [day] => Wed
                                                           [high] => 38
                                                           [low] => 34
                                                           [text] => Cloudy
                                                       )

                                                   [7] => stdClass Object
                                                       (
                                                           [code] => 28
                                                           [date] => 12 May 2016
                                                           [day] => Thu
                                                           [high] => 37
                                                           [low] => 33
                                                           [text] => Mostly Cloudy
                                                       )

                                                   [8] => stdClass Object
                                                       (
                                                           [code] => 5
                                                           [date] => 13 May 2016
                                                           [day] => Fri
                                                           [high] => 37
                                                           [low] => 33
                                                           [text] => Rain And Snow
                                                       )

                                                   [9] => stdClass Object
                                                       (
                                                           [code] => 30
                                                           [date] => 14 May 2016
                                                           [day] => Sat
                                                           [high] => 47
                                                           [low] => 31
                                                           [text] => Partly Cloudy
                                                       )

                                               )
   ```

Comment: It's obviously `$value['distance']` or something else, because array keys can't be arrays.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something incredibly obvious, your first foreach loop is turning an array into key/value pairs. While $value could still be an array, I see no way for $key to be an array, and therefore, $key['distance'] is always going to say "illegal offset".

Comment: Show us the contents of `$obj`

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my answer above...

foreach works one of two ways:

1)

```
foreach($variable as $thing)
{
    // Do something
}
```

2)

```
foreach($variable as $index=>$thing)
{
    // Do something
}
```

In both examples, $variable must be an array or object, and it will iterate over $variable.

In the first example, $thing will be the current value (the current element of the object or array). In the second example, $index is the index of the object or array (and it is automatically assigned), and $thing is the current value (again, the current element of the object or array.)

So, let's say this is your array

```
$variable = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
foreach($variable as $thing)
{
    echo $thing.'<br/>';
}
```

You would get:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

If instead you used the second version of foreach....

```
$variable = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
foreach($variable as $index=>$thing)
{
    echo 'Element '. $index . ' = ' $thing.'<br/>';
}
```

You'd get:

```
Element 0 = foo
Element 1 = bar
Element 2 = baz
```

The important takeaway from the second form of foreach is that $index will **never** be an array. It might be a numeric index, it might be a string index. It will never be an array.

So, in your example $key['distance'] will always say that it's an illegal offset, because $key is not an array to begin with.

**Edit:**
Using your example above:

```
foreach ($obj->query->results->channel->units as $key => $value) {
    if($key == 'distance') {
        echo $key . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" . "<br><br>";
        echo $value . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }
}
```

Now, if it turns out the value for the key 'distance' is not a string, it's going to have a different error for you.

Comment: Ok I understand it, how can I obtain a key value that I know of foreach
in your example by example "foo"

Comment: I just added an example from your original question.